# How to understand pad_sequences in keras.preprocessing?

Tags: neural-network, keras, tensorflow

I understand now the meaning for pad_sequence but wouldn't truncate the sentence will lead to loss of data and how will the model correctly identify the sentiment with incomplete data

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42943291/what-does-keras-io-preprocessing-sequence-pad-sequences-do

Comment: What kind of data are you working with?

Comment: @JahKnows I am working on text data

Comment: Can we see some example of the data and what you are trying to do?